# Handlebars JS: Including <li>, <br>, and other HTML tags in data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I want to use handlebars to display a series of data in an unordered list, split between "title" and "articles." However, some of the articles will contain different HTML tags, be it `<a>` tags for link. If you take a look at my code below, when the data is appended to the DOM, rather than showing a link like 'You can read more about it here', it says the actual HTML anchor tags. Does anyone know a way around this?

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Consider the following template:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div style='margin: 20px'>
        <ul style='list-style-type: none; width:500px'>
            <h4 style='padding:10px; overflow: auto'>General Credit</h4>
            {{#each this}}
            <li style='padding:10px; overflow: auto'>
                <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                <p>{{article}}</p>
            </li>
            {{/each}}

        </ul>
    </div>

</script>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
//Data for Articles
var articleData = [
{
    title: "My title here",
    article: "You can learn more about it <a href='https://www.google.com'>here</a>"
}
];

//Get Template From Script Tag
var source1 = $("#my-template").html();
//Compile Template
var template1 = Handlebars.compile(source1);
$("#myDiv").append(template1(articleData));
```

Comment: Why do you have a h4 as a child of an ul?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use triple curly braces:

```
<li style='padding:10px; overflow: auto'>
    <h3>{{{title}}}</h3>
    <p>{{{article}}}</p>
</li>
```

So that handlebars doesn't escape the HTML code within your string.

[Here](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) the reference.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use triple brackets to escape html.
Try {{{article}}}

Answer (score 1):

Simple you {} {} helper call is a simple identifier, followed by zero or more parameters (separated by space). Each parameter is a Handlebars expression.
{{{link story}}}
In this case, link is the name of a Handlebars helper, and story is a parameter to the helper. Handlebars evaluates parameters in exactly the same way described above in "Basic Usage".

Answer (score 0):

Reread the documentation more carefully. Simply put {{{}}} instead of {{}} around the article in my template, and the HTML tags render fine now.

Handlebars documentation: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Comment: also note that heading tags are invalid children of `<ul>`